# How to add extraPort in bitnami headless service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I want to add extra port into a headless service provided by bitnami helm templates. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically these charts allow values to be overridden or added.
The Bitnami github repo for the chart you're looking at should have an "extraPorts" value that you can override.

For example, the postgresql chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql/#installing-the-chart has a value `primary.service.extraPorts` which takes a list of extra ports as input.
Thus, you could create a values file like

```
primary:
  service:
    extraPorts:
      - 8080
      - 8081
```

and pass the values file to your `helm upgrade` or `helm install` command using the `-f <filename>` flag.

Comment: That's for the default helm chart. My question is: can you add extraPorts for this template: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql/templates/primary/svc.yaml